# Do digits after the decimal point have a specific name?

Tags: word-request, mathematics, numbers

I would like to know if there's a name for "digits after the decimal point" (in only one or two words). For instance in french these digits are called "décimales".

I've found "decimal places", but I am not sure it is synonym, for instance, considering the number 7.9362, would it be correct to say that its decimal places are 9, 3, 6 and 2?

EDIT: several answers are useful, so it's not easy to choose only one...

Comment: The collocation ***decimal places*** is usually only used in expressions like *This value is accurate to four decimal places* - meaning the (first) four digits ***after the decimal point*** have been specified and are known to be correct. You wouldn't call one of the individual digits a "decimal place". Although it's evocative of a completely different way of writing non-integers, I'd still be inclined to say that any digits after the decimal point are (or *represent*) the ***fractional part***. But *accurate to four **significant digits*** says nothing about where the decimal point might be.

Comment: You could say, for example, "What number is in the second decimal place?" That makes perfect sense. Also, each position _does_ have a name - "tenths place", "hundredths place", "thousandths place", and so on. But I doubt those descriptions would be used by an actual mathematician.

Comment: Technically: *digits*. Colloquially? *decimals* is acceptable. Only mathematicians and pedants will correct you on it. E.g., [*How many decimals of Pi do you people remember by heart?*](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-many-decimals-of-pi-do-you-remember.1435/)

Comment: @Mazura, *decimals* is unambiguous, whereas *digits* is not.

Comment: "Digits after the decimal point" seems to me to be a fine way to express the desired concept. I think "decimal places" refers more to the positions of the digits than to the digits actually found in those positions. "Decimals" works too in an appropriate context (such as the example given above).

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake, I wouldn't say unambiguous. When I hear "decimal" I think of base-10 digits as opposed to binary or hexadecimal. Like "102.3" has 4 decimal digits. "dead.beef" has 8 hexadecimal digits. :)

Comment: @JoL I meant *decimals* specifically, not *decimal digits*. The latter would indeed refer to everything before and after the decimal (excuse me :P) point.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake, yeah but *decimals* is short for *decimal digits*, isn't it? At least, if you look up the definition of "decimals" you get "[A number written in base-10](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/decimal)" and "[expressed in or utilizing a decimal system](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decimal)".

Comment: @JoL Have a look at the second MW defininition (*:any real number expressed in base 10; especially :decimal fraction*)

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake, but it doesn't have to be, and that's what makes it ambiguous. :)

Comment: @JoL Neither dictionary covers the plural version, which to my mind has a distinct meaning. If someone said to me that some number has *n* decimals, I'd assume they meant *non-integral decimal digits*.

Comment: @JoL I suppose there is *some* ambiguity, since we interpret *decimals* differently. Maybe I'm affected by my own native language, where *decimaler* (lit. *decimals*) always refers to fractional digits. Not sure what most native speakers of English would make of it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can call the digits to the left of the decimal point [integer digits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22integer%20digits%22) or [integral digits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22integral%20digits%22) and those to the right of the decimal point [fraction digits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fraction%20digits%22) or [fractional digits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fractional%20digits%22).

Java I/O, Harold (2006):

> For instance, in the number 31.415, there are two integer digits and
>   three fraction digits.

Microprocessor Engineering, Holdsworth (2013):

> ...where n is the number of integral digits and m the number of
>   fractional digits.

Perhaps these terms are not well-established, but they are used in the literature and will be understood in the appropriate context.

Comment: If your context is math. If your context is just everyday speech, these  might be a bit confusing.

Comment: I chose your answer because it also works with my example: considering the number 7.9362, it is then correct to say that its fraction digits are 9, 3, 6 and 2

Comment: @Azor-Ahai The only context I can think of in everyday life where you'd want a name for the digits before versus after the decimal point of a number would be if that number was a price. And in that case, you'd just refer to the "number of pounds/dollars/euros" versus "number of pence/cents". In any other case, the fact that you're talking about the digits in a number means you're almost certainly talking about mathematics.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I mean if you're talking about "mathematics," sure, but if you're doing some back-of-the-napkin math, the might be less understandable.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai What term would you suggest to apply to this mathematical situation without using formal mathematical terminology?  The common way of describing it would be to say "the numbers to the right [or left] of the decimal point", and I fear any specific term beyond this could be rejected as "mathematics" using an argument similar to your own.

Comment: @DarrenRinger I just wanted to provide a little context that these are perhaps beyond casual speech, I'm sure a non-mathematician has had occasion to refer to those numbers specifically. I'm a scientist, but not a mathematician, and I confess I'd be confused by someone bringing up the "integral digits" at first blush. I think it's especially helpful to bring up extra background information on ELL.

Comment: So, an integer is a number that has/contains no fractional digits?

Answer (score 34):

[*Fractional part*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalPart.html) is both used in mathematics and other fields where such things are discussed, and easily understood by lay readers.

Comment: This could also be non decimal fractions like 3/4 so not fully descriptive.

Comment: The same objection (about fractions that are not expressed in decimal form) applies to the definition of _mantissa_ that was offered in another answer.

Comment: @KalleMP "What's the name of the Speaker of the US House of Representatives?" "Paul Ryan." "There could also be other people called Paul Ryan, so not fully descriptive." The question asks for the name of a particular thing; this answer gives that name. So what if that name could also apply to other things?

Comment: @KalleMP In mathematics and computing, a radix point is the symbol used in numerical representations to separate the integer part of a number (to the left of the radix point) from its [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) (to the right of the radix point). In base 10 notation, the radix point is more commonly called the decimal point. Similarly, the term "binary point" is used for base 2.

Comment: Can I say "a number that doesn't include a fractional part"?

Answer (score 28):

The fractional part of a number is known as the [*Mantissa*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mantissa&t=crmtb01).

The mantissa is defined as the positive fractional part of a real number.

Your suggestion of *decimal places* is usually used to specify a number of digits that must follow the decimal point.  The term *mantissa* makes no such restriction.  It defines all the digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Note though that Mantissa is not a commonly used word outside of mathematics.

Comment: *Mantissa* is often used only with logarithms. Confusingly in programming and computer science it's often used of the entire significand of a number expressed in scientific notation.

Comment: @JonHanna That's because most floating-point representations use an implicit radix point.

Comment: [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand) cites Donald Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming* with "it is an abuse of terminology to call the fraction part a mantissa, since this concept has quite a different meaning in connection with logarithms"

Comment: Have to agree with @Jon Hanna - I have always know the "mantissa" to be the fractional part of base-10 logarithms - whilst the integral is called the "characteristic". It would be confusing I think to refer to the fractional part of *any* number as the "mantissa"

Comment: Using the word *mantissa* would be confusing to 99% of the entire English speaking world. I know it'd be kinda fickle to DV this just because it's offering a word that *I've* never heard of to someone trying to learn English, so I won't... just saying ;)

Comment: +1, but I'm a native speaker and have never heard of this word.

Comment: Of the few people who recognize the word _mantissa_ at all, most will think it means something other than what OP wanted. "Confusing to 99%" may be an understatement. I wouldn't use that word for the fractional part of a number.

Comment: Also, according to the definition cited here, the mantissa of -1.234 is 0.766, which I think is _not at all_ what OP wanted.

Comment: For the record, I'm a native (British) English speaker and instantly thought of _mantissa_, even before seeing this answer. While the term might have _originated_ to allow talking about the "whole" and "fractional" parts of logarithms, I've always understood it as being applicable to any number (how do you know whether "3.1415" is "just a number" or "log 1,385.1601859245"?).

Answer (score 5):

They're called *decimals*. This is a term everyone will understand.

> If a billion decimals of pi were printed in ordinary type, they would stretch from New York City to the middle of Kansas.

[Panic in Level 4: Cannibals, Killer Viruses, and Other Journeys to the Edge of Science by Richard Preston](https://books.google.se/books?id=hrdqCFEeFJYC&pg=PA20&dq=%22decimals%20of%20pi%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22decimals%20of%20pi%22&f=false)

Comment: Just wondering why decimals of pi are special - surely a string of a billion `a`s would have the same effect?

Comment: It is an irrational number. @boboquack

Comment: Would it be correct to say that '4' is one decimal of '9.046'?

Comment: @Saibot I know that, but `aaaaaa` takes up the same amount of space as `3.14159` or `anyone` or `^%&$*(`

Comment: If all the decimals of pi (or any other number) were printed in ordinary type, the universe would run out of space and energy. Not so special after all. :)

Comment: @MaskedMan I think you meant to say "or any other irrational number" instead of any other number.

Comment: @Enkouyami depends on whether you're going to print the infinite number of implicit trailing zeroes I guess.

Comment: @boboquack Only if you use a Monospace font ;)